# Gedit plugin installation

Tags: ide, editor, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'm trying to install a gedit plugin: the https://github.com/elijahr/gedit-rename plugin, to be able to rename files in the ide.
Well, I can't install it despite following the installation instructions.

In fact, I've never managed to install a Gedit plugin in my entire life. And I tried many times.

If somebody has some time and could help me make it work that would be nice.

Or point me to another ide that allows renaming files and has a vertical split view.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

There is a plugin in gedit that will let you rename files.

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Plugin -> File Browser Panel : and select it and the CLose.

Now you will see a file browser on left side and you could just rename files from there

[image: rename gedit]

For different ide: there are many like depending on the language you are working with:

**General**: sublime text editor, emacs, vim, geany

**python**: pycharm, anaconda, enthought canopy

**c#,c++**: visual studio(for windows), Qt, codeblocks

**java**: eclipse, netbeans, Qt